# ¿Cómo saber en el código de versión de la aplicación dentro del java?

Tags: android

Buenas comunidad, estoy buscando como sacar en el `Java` de mi propia aplicación, sacar el número de versión de la aplicación. He visto que llamando al método `getApplication().getApplicationInfo()` te trae alguna información, pero no veo el código de la versión por ningún sitio. Por si alguno no sabe a que me refiero todavía, es en el `gradle` del proyecto la siguiente linea:
`versionCode 1`. Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtenerlo de estas dos formas:

**Forma 1:**

```
try {
     PackageInfo informacion = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);

     //Obtienes versionCode ubicado en el gradle
     int versionCode = informacion.versionCode;

    //Obtienes versionName ubicado en el gradle
     String versionName = informacion.versionName;



} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Forma 2:**

```
import com.nombre_tu_paquete.BuildConfig;


int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;

String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```